# Why antimicrobial resistance is based mainly on antibiotic use?

Tags: antibiotic-resistance

Why antimicrobial resistance is based mainly on antibiotics use and not so much on antifungal or antivirus drugs? Why, when someone speaks about antimicrobial resistance, refers mostly to antibiotitic resistance and not so much to antifungal resistance or antivirus resistance?

All this has to do because of the overuse of the specific drugs(antibiotic), or there are biological and genetical mechanisms that make the antibiotics the main reason of antimicrobial resistance instead of anti-fungal or other drugs?

Comment: Can you do some research first on this? We prefer well-researched questions where the OP has made some effort on their own to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually a lot simpler. Antibacterials are the most commonly used antimicrobials by far and a consequence of this is that many people use antimicrobrial and antibacterial interchangably. You're right that antimicrobials are substances that target microorganisms such as bacteria, archaea, viruses, and eukaryotes. As stated earlier, the reality is that we use antibacterials far more than any other type of antimicrobial. Other antimicrobials are either toxic to us because they target other eukaryotes like fungi or they are very limited in what they target like many antivirals. Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Antibiotic resistance is more in the public eye because the general population is more likely to use or be prescribed antibiotics than antivirals.  Antibiotic resistance has also been in the news more lately because

1: persons infected with superbugs that resist antibiotic treatment make salacious news articles.  e.g. https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/4528838/bleach-antibacterial-soap-antibiotics-mrsa-infection/

2: it is now recognized that the use of antibiotics to promote growth in livestock is [responsible for a lot of evolved antibiotic resistance](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/pdf/10.1089/fpd.2006.0066) - these are large populations of animals that are fed antibiotics all the time. 
 In the US until very recently, [80% of antibiotics sold were used as animal growth promoters](http://www.cidrap.umn.edu/news-perspective/2016/12/fda-antibiotic-use-food-animals-continues-rise).

It does not take much googling to read about other circumstances where evolved drug resistance is a problem.  Resistance to antivirals is hugely important for persons with HIV and their caregivers.
http://www.who.int/hiv/topics/drugresistance/en/

If you are not in one of these populations you may not be aware of the issue.  Other examples include drug resistant malaria and drug resistant tuberculosis.  These diseases are not so problematic in the developed world which may be why they are less in the public eye than superbugs in the senior's home.